# how to clear background data when sign out

Tags: android

I have been writing a multiple accounts manage module. What I want to do is to lead user to Accounts list activity when signing out. The problems is when user press back button, it resumed the background activity and user still can use the app even signed out. And it doesn`t work either when I cleared account info in database and SharedPreference.

For better understanding I describe the problem again.

For example, I have three activities, A, B and C. A works as main activity with a list, B works as the settings menu activity and C works as the account list Activity.

When I navigate from A to B click "Sign Out" menu in B, then the process flow goes from B to C.
Because it asks user to choose (if has) or login an account.

Now the problem is when user press back button, it can go back from C to A rather than exit the app (go to home screen). See the screenshot blow.[image]

Since user already signed out, I doesn`t make sense to navigate back from C to A. C should be the only visible Activity at this circumstance.

But I don`t know how to implement this, I already clear account info in local storage, so it should not be the settings problem.

So how to clear the background activity A?

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a flag suppose "isLoggedIn" in shared Preferences or database. In your launcher/first activity check this flag and decide whether to call login activity or direct xyz activity. And when you clear data again call your launcher/first activity with clear_top flag in intent.

Comment: the problem is A->B->C, then press back button, C->A. So the logic is C goes to (restores) A from background, data of A was stored in memory, and I wonder how to clear the data of A?

Comment: means you don't want to come back to A from C ?

Comment: most times I need to come back to A from C except when signing out.

Comment: I am confused. whether you want to come back to A or not?

Comment: C is settings menu, it includes a lot of settings, sign out is just one of them.

Comment: on signout, call System.exit(0); otherwise user will automatically come to A when back pressed

Answer (score 0):

try this code in Activity C

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(startMain);
        }
```

Comment: this is not general, because C needs to go back to A sometimes when user needs to do other operations except signing out.

Comment: B seems to be an alertdialog.So you can finish the activity A when going to sign-out by calling finish() method. Other wise just navigate to C.